# How to shutdown/restart my UWP-Application?

Tags: c#, uwp, restart, shutdown, windows-iot-core-10

I'm working on a programm for RaspberryPi with Windows IoT core 17763. My IDE is Visual Studio 2019. I use C# and UWP for my programm.

Restart and shutdown doesn't work.
For these functions the app has 3 buttons.

- Button Exit: termination of the app and start the IoT core app.
- Button Restart: full reboot of the system.
- Button Shutdown: full shutdown the system.

How does my app behave?

1. while debugging: All 3 buttons just terminate the app and the debugging ends.
2. when app is in autostart: All 3 Buttons perform a restart of the app. No shutdown, no reboot of the system, no IoT core app.

Here the relevant code of my application

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using Windows.System;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //button to exit application
    private void FlyoutExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Exit();
    }

    //button to restart system
    private void FlyoutReboot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Restart, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
    }

    //button to shutdown system
    private void FlyoutShutdown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
    }

}
```

Here is the Package.appxmanifest

```
<Package
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">
<Capabilities>
<iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices"/>
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When the application exits in debugging mode, visual studio will dis-connect the remote debugging. The behavior is correct. After the application exits, Windows IoT Core will start [the default app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/setupdefaultapp) which is configured as start-up.
2. **ShutdownManager** requires the use of the IoT systemManagement capability. You need to add the following to Package.appmanifest, otherwise, the app will exit with an exception.

   `<iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>`

Comment: The behavior while debugging is clear for me. But when the app is not in debug. I added my Package.appxmanifest to the main post. I don't get any exception. The app just restarts.

Comment: @TonicLoyal, when the app is in debug mode, does shutdown/restart work with no exception? ShutdownManager works fine for me even the app in debug mode or not.

Comment: If possible, could you please share your project?

Comment: no exception even in debug. In debug the app just closes and returns to the IoT core app. How can i share the project? Does StackOverflow support this, or does it need to be uploaded externally?

Comment: I found my mistake. I copied the buttons for reboot and shutdown from the exit button. So I forgot to change the Click="Exit_Click" in XAML. All 3 had the same click. So no matter what i clicked, the current.Exit() was always taken. My only question now is, how to exit the app and start the IoT core app. ANy idea?